# Whether I need to define my own hash and equal method?

Tags: java, hashcode

If I need to use `InfoName` as the `key` of a `HashMap`, do I need to define my own `hashCode()` and `equals()` method? I think it's not necessary, since the String `name` variable will be enough to make sure each object of `InfoName` is different.

```
public class InfoName {
    enum Type {
        company, product;
    }

    public String name;
    public Type type;

    public InfoName(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the map going to know to use the name variable if you don't define equals() and hashCode() to tell it to do so?

Comment: If you're going to use an `InfoName` instance as the key then, yes, you need to redefine the `hashCode` and `equals`.  but since you only seem to care about the `name` variable, why not use *that* as the key? Then you don't need to worry about any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the String "name" variable will be enough to make sure each object of
>   InfoName is different

If you only want to use the `name` in the `InfoName`, then  just make `String` type `name` as the `key` as it already override `equals()` and `hashCode()`  .

OR

You need to override  `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `InfoName` class, else how would JVM knows on which attribute/criteria you are using for hashing and equality check.

Comment: I need to know its type for each name, so I need to bundle the type and name together as an object.  For example, some names will have the same type, and based on this, I want to count the number of names with the same type.

Comment: @martin so your whole goal is to find the count of names with the same type?

Comment: print all the names with counts of each, but at the same time print counts of each type.

Comment: Will `name` be always unique for all `InfoName` objects

Comment: It could be that the same name can belong to different types.

Comment: Then in that case `InfoName ` as key also wont solve your problem , coz combination of `name` / `type`  should be unique else the `value` will be replaced with the new `value` if the same `name` comes again. But a t the same time you also want the names with counts of each. So i would rather prefer a `List` of `InfoName ` type and then iterate over it to have your logics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to have InfoName as key you need to override both.
 You an have something like

```
public class Test {
    enum Type {
        company, product;
    }

    public String name;
    public Type type;

    public Test(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {//or do what you like
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Test test = (Test) o;

        if (!name.equals(test.name)) return false;
        if (type != test.type) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + type.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Basically your editor provides features of overriding hashcode and equals. Have a look here [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's not necessary, since the String "name" variable will be
>   enough to make sure each object of InfoName is different.

I would recommend not to use `name` as the hash key because it seems a bad candidate. I mean could you have multiple objects with the same product name? In that case you would have many collisions.